# Periodic points of prime period two if $r>3$

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, population-dynamics

> Consider the discrete Logistic model $P_{n+1}=r P_n\left(1-P_n\right)=g_r\left(P_n\right), 0 \leq r \leq 4$. Find the fixed point and analysis its stability. For what value of $r$, do the non-hyperbolic fixed points occur? Show that $g$ has periodic points of prime period two if $r>3$.

Fixed points are,
$$
\begin{align}
P^*&=rP^*(1-P^*)\\
P^*(r-rP^*-1)&=0\\
P^*=0&\textrm{ or }P^*=\frac{r-1}{r}
\end{align}
$$
Now, I suspect the range of $r$ needs to be split into many cases. Is $r=1,<1,\geq1$ enough? How could I know that more splits are necessary? And I couldn't figure out **"For what value of $r$, do the non-hyperbolic fixed points occur? Show that $g$ has periodic points of prime period two if $r>3$."**

non-hyperbolic for continuous version is $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$. From where I guess the discrete case will be $P_{n+1}-P_n=\nabla P_n=1$. but the discrete model seems not compatible with my guess. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should be looking for $g_r'(P^*_r)=\pm 1$.

Comment: Why $g_r'=\pm 1$ is used? @LutzLehmann Sorry but for discrete models, I couldn't relate everything with the continuous version. Like in the continuous version, there was no chaotic nature in the logistic model but it seems the discrete model has by varying in the value of $r$.

Comment: The linearization at the fixed point is neither expanding nor contracting if all the eigenvalues are on the unit circle (and simple). In one dimension this means that the derivative has absolute value one. See [search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=logistic+map+fixed+period*+bifurcat*) for context.